# "ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib" When I already installed CMake and added it path

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmake, pip, dlib

I have installed cmake and added it to path.

Here is what the error looks like when I try to install dlib using pip:

```py
C:\Users\Zack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts>pip install dlib
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.24.0.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      running build_ext

      ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
  Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib
  Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for dlib did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [9 lines of output]
      running install
      C:\Users\Zack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      running build_ext

      ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> dlib

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I tried downloading the dlib wheel and installing it like that:

```py
C:\Users\Zack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts>pip install "D:\Users\ZACK\Downloads\dlib-18.17.100-cp27-none-win32.whl"
```

Output

```py
ERROR: dlib-18.17.100-cp27-none-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I tried installing the wheel with a url:

```py
C:\Users\Zack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts> pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/da/06/bd3e241c4eb0a662914b3b4875fc52dd176a9db0d4a2c915ac2ad8800e9e/dlib-19.7.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#md5=b7330a5b2d46420343fbed5df69e6a3f
```

Output

```py
ERROR: dlib-19.7.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Comment: Did you restart your shell / do some other action to get your shell to pick up the changed `PATH` variable? Do you see what you expect when you do `echo $PATH`?

Answer (score 0):

your cmake path is not in path. I hope if it helps after installing the package.

THe choice of package can't be any arbitrary. In your case,  dlib-19.7.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl might not be the appropriate one.

Try running "`pip debug --verbose`" then see, which version are matching with those given in the output of the above command. Then and then only, wheel version is supported and it will be installed.